# Creating new .php file using php

Tags: php

```
    <form name= "create" action=".php" method = "get">

        <input type="text" name="filename">
        <input type="submit" value="create" />
        <br>
    </form>
```

I have this form that will accept a name and eventually create a php file with the same file name. Is it possible to be done ?

Comment: Red flag, red flag. XY problem! Why do you think you need to create a new .php file automatically?!

Comment: @deceze i am working in a program that will accept data, save it to the database, show all data on the database and all those data is hyperlinked that whenever you click it it will pop a new window that will show you all the information about the data

Comment: And why do you think you need to create new PHP files for that?!

Comment: its just my logic, im new in php, am i doing it wrong ?

Comment: Yes. Ever heard of passing parameters in the URL? `example.com/data.php?id=42`. If not, please read more books or tutorials.

Answer (score 3):

**Disclaimer:**  Allowing clients to create `.php` files poses great threats and I am not responsible for damages to your server.

Yes, it is possible.

Your form will send the person to a `creator.php`, passing the filename by `GET`.

`creator.php` will look like this:

```
<?php
file_put_contents($_GET["filename"].".php","This is my PHP file made by PHP!");
?>
```

Be careful though, as allowing the client to create files at their own will can be a huge security hole for hackers.

**A better way** to do this is to pass the table you want to get in the title using `?` and then have a single page parse the query string and grab the correct database.  It will avoid messes and havoc on your server.

Something like `data_getter.php`:

```
<?php
$database_name=$_SERVER["QUERY_STRING"]
// I don't know what kind of database you are using, but you
// will get the data here and put it into $database_contents.
echo $database_contents;
?>
```

This method will require more work, but will be much cleaner and safer.

Answer (score 1):

Of course it can be done, you can create the file using the following code, of course the directory that stores the file must have write permission

```
$my_file = $_GET['filename'] + '.php';
$handle = fopen($my_file, 'w') or die('Cannot open file:  '.$my_file);
```

you can also append, open, etc of file operations

But I must warn you, using this type of operation you are making your server under risk of hacking people can write what ever they want